# OTRS Database server keep increasing it's storage size, not working when deleting tickets with generic agent. how to save storage space w/o add sas?

Tags: vmware-esxi, centos7, otrs

Does anyone know what need to remove to save space in vm level, os level or db level in a safest way without ruining the server itself? I'm having a problem with short storage space now and we still don't have a sas drive to add because of procurement problems in our department, and I still figure out if i should delete the vmdk or vmem in datastore or delete data within os level or db level. Is there any way to increase storage space without adding another sas drive?